# Administrator account does not work on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

I've enabled disabled administrator account on Windows 10 and logged into it but seems like it doesn't work. For example, if I open a command prompt from folder (shift+right click), it opens a simple cmd, not admin's. And I still see UAC's shields when right click folders/file on disk C. I enabled the account on Windows 8 earlier and it worked well. With this issue I can't do most things.

Comment: I believe you need to disable UAC completely in order for things to run as administrator automatically

Comment: By default, just logging in as Administrator doesn't mean everything you do is elevated. you still need to use UAC to request admin elevation when you want an app to have admin capabilities. In modern windows, members of the Administrators group are able to request elevation, but they are a limited user unless they request it. Personally I think disabling UAC is a really bad idea, and that its not much of a pain to deal with (though not as nice as sudo). Just my two bits.

Comment: @Koliat - An application when ran on Windows 8 and above, does not automatically run as an elevated process, unless the user elevates it.  *You cannot fully disable UAC in Windows 8 and above.*

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by reinstalling Windows 10 from USB. Earlier I did it only through official website. UAC shields gone that tell me that all works.